# Need to copy a multi-sheet spreadsheet with all data and formatting Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy a 2-page spreadsheet in Google Drive to another folder.

Here is where I've managed to bungle myself to;

```
function clearRange() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Internal copy');
  sheet.getRange('B3:B7').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('D3:D5').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B12:C15').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B20:C23').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B28:C31').clearContent();
}

function copySpreadSheet() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sourceName = source.getSheetName();
  var sValues = source.getDataRange().getValues();
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Mcnlyknqmtf2u_TEhbWxwzYqlxGw39Sno2bOXgkErb4');
  source.copyTo('destination')
  var destinationSheet = destination.getSheetByName('Copy of '+sourceName)
  destinationSheet.getRange(1,1,sValues.length,sValues[0].length).setValues(sValues);

function main() {
  copySpreadSheet("Internal Estimate invoice Blundell");
}
```

Please note the first bit is another function to clear cells after saving.  This is a quote template I want my shop to use without messing with the quote.  I want them to input data, save it as a copy, and then reset the fields to zero, ready for the next quote.

Any help would be appreciated!

**** UPDATE ********

So, I have gotten it to work somewhat.  Here is my new code;

```
function copySheetValuesV4(){
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheets = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.create(sourceSpreadsheet.getName()+' Final');
    for (var i = 0; i < sourceSheets.length; i++){
      var sourceSheet = sourceSheets[i];
      if (!sourceSheet.isSheetHidden()) {
        var sourceSheetName = sourceSheet.getSheetName();
        var sValues = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
        sourceSheet.copyTo(destination)
        var destinationSheet = destination.getSheetByName('Copy of '+sourceSheetName).setName(sourceSheetName);
        destinationSheet.getRange(1,1,sValues.length,sValues[0].length).setValues(sValues);// overwrite all formulas that the copyTo preserved */

      }
    destination.getSheetByName("sheet1").hideSheet() // Remove the default "sheet1" */
  }
}
```

It makes a copy in my /root folder, which is fine for now, however it doesn't copy any of the formula, nor does it copy the protected ranges.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

- You want to copy only the sheets which is not hidden to new Spreadsheet.
- You want to keep the format and formulas when the sheets are copied.
- For the destination Spreadsheet, you want to hide the sheet of `sheet1`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers. In this answer, `copySheetValuesV4()` is modified.

The flow of this sample script is as follows.

### Flow:

1. Copy the source Spreadsheet.
2. Delete the hidden sheets.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, above flow is used as a simple script.

#### Sample script:

```
function copySheetValuesV4() {
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dst = sourceSpreadsheet.copy(sourceSpreadsheet.getName()+' Final');
  var sheets = dst.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].isSheetHidden()) {
      dst.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
    }
  }
  dst.getSheetByName("sheet1").hideSheet();
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, above flow is used. And, in order to delete the history of the Spreadsheet that the hidden sheets were deleted, the temporal Spreadsheet is copied as the output Spreadsheet. Then, the new Spreadsheet is moved to the specific folder. The temporal Spreadsheet is moved to the trash box.

#### Sample script:

```
function copySheetValuesV4() {
  var folderId = "###"; // Please set the destination folder ID.

  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var temp = sourceSpreadsheet.copy("temp");
  var sheets = temp.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].isSheetHidden()) {
      temp.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
    }
  }
  temp.getSheetByName("sheet1").hideSheet();
  var id = temp.copy(sourceSpreadsheet.getName()+' Final').getId();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).addFile(file);
  file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
  DriveApp.getFileById(temp.getId()).setTrashed(true);
}
```

#### References:

- [copy(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#copyname)
- [deleteSheet(sheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#deletesheetsheet)
- [Class DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.